# Specific use of になる together with て-form

Tags: て-form

I am learning Japanese via Glossika. I have now come across a construction which I do not really understand and cannot find an explanation online.

The sentences in question are always of the form

> て-form of a verb + になります。

E.g.

> 日本語 を 勉強し 始めて に なります。

(slightly altered to not use the concrete sentence from Glossika)

Here are orignal examples (as well as a similar one I found online)

> 1. あなた は 先生 に なって どのぐらい に なります か?
> 2. 英語 を 勉強し 始めて 半年 に なります
> 3. 日本 に きて どのくらい に なりますか?

Can someone explain the usage of になる in this case. I know that this means 'to become' but so far I have only seen it used either with nouns or adjectives.

Comment: Could you maybe "use the concrete sentence from Glossika"? It looks like you might have altered the original sentence a bit too much.

Comment: Ok. These are two examples
1. 英語 を 勉強し 始めて 半年 に なります。
2. あなた は 先生 に なって どのぐらい に なります か?

Comment: Ah, good. It seems that you for some reason left out 半年 & どのぐらい in "て-form of a verb + になります". Can you figure out by looking at examples what goes between the *te*-form and になります?

Comment: Ok, so if 半年 is what this what makes the sentence correct, I still do not understand it quite cleary or would it literally translate as
'I have begun studying english and?? it has a become half a year'
Still not clear to me how to interpret the usage of the て-form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two key concepts to understanding this sentence: the て form, and なる.

**Function of -て**

Firstly, the -て form of the verb is used to string events together, usually in sequential order:

> 朝ご飯を食べて、シャワーを浴びた。
>   I ate breakfast, and then took a shower.

When the second phrase expresses a passage of time, it describes how long it has (or had) been since the first phrase happened:

> 学校が始まって一か月がたった。
>   It's been a month since school started.

Thus, we can understand the first part of your example as:

> 英語を勉強し始めて
>   (I) started learning English... (and then something else happened).

To a native English speaker, this kind of construction for telling time looks strange (yet logical), but it is very common in Japanese.

---

**なる**

As for なる, it still is used with a noun here. なる is *only* used with adjectives and nouns. In fact, to use it with a verb, you have to turn the verb into a noun with よう or こと so that you *can* attach に. For example:

> ピアノをひけるようになった。
>   I became able to play the piano well

So in the second part of your (full) example, なる is used with the noun 半年, to indicate the passage of time:

> 半年になります
>   It becomes a half year/half a year passes

---

**The original sentence**

So, putting these concepts together, we can decipher your sentence:

> 英語を勉強し始めて半年になります
>   I started studying English, and then it became half a year. (lit)
>   I've been studying English for half a year.

Comment: `ピアノをひけるになった。` >> You meant to type ひける**よう**になった, no?

Comment: @Schokolade Yes, I did. Thank you for catching that!

Answer (score 4):

In the expression:

> 「Verb in て-form + (length of time) + に + なる/なります」,

「～～になる」 does ***not*** mean "to become ~~".

Instead, it means "***(length of time) has passed***".

When using this expression in asking questions regarding how much time someone has been doing something, you just replace the (length of time) by 「どれくらい」 or 「どのくらい」 and attach a 「か」 at the very end of the question.

This should explain the structures and meanings of all of the example sentences you have listed above.